# MySQL a left join and a few inner joins in a same query

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have few tables namely.

1. categories
2. items
3. restaurant_items
4. restaurants
5. new_sponsoreds
6. regions

If I briefly explain these tables,

`categories` is food categories. eg:- **Cake**

`item` is like a subcategory for food. eg:- **Chocolate Cake**.

`restaurant_items` is an instance of item which belongs to a particular restaurant. eg:- **Chocolate cake in ABC restaurant**.

`restaurants` is as it names implies just a restaurant and `regions` is an area where the `restaurant` located at.

**MOST IMPORTANT ONE** new_sponsoreds is where restaurants promote their food items as advertisements.

```
runday    | category_id | restaurant_id

2018-12-5 | 23          | 45
```

This `new_sponsoreds` table indicates, We need to run advertisements on `restaurant_items` where `category_id` is 23 in restaurant's id is 45.

**MY USE CASE**

Get all the `restaurant_items` from a given `region` and then filter those

`restaurant_items` by a `category` and finally **right outer join** this results with `new_sponsoreds`.

So that a food app user can get `restaurant_items` from a `region` (NEW YORK) and filter it by a `category` (CAKES).

This query is for get that `restaurant_items`.

```
SELECT restaurant_items.* FROM test2.restaurant_items
inner join items on restaurant_items.item_id = items.Item_id
inner join categories on items.category_id = categories.id
inner join restaurants on restaurant_items.restaurant_id = restaurants.Restaurant_id
where restaurants.region_id = 7 and categories.id = 33
```

This is works fine. But when I try to join this results with the `new_sponsoreds` table like this,

```
SELECT restaurant_items.*,new_sponsoreds.* FROM test2.restaurant_items
inner join items on restaurant_items.item_id = items.Item_id
inner join categories on items.category_id = categories.id
inner join restaurants on restaurant_items.restaurant_id = restaurants.Restaurant_id
left outer join new_sponsoreds on categories.id = new_sponsoreds.category_id
where restaurants.region_id = 7 and categories.id = 33
and new_sponsoreds.runday = current_date()
```

**This query returns empty set of rows.**
But what I expect was this query will gives me all the `restaurant_items` filter from a `region` and a `category_id` and if a restaurant promote a category in today, this also will include the results.

```
id |restaurant_id | Item_id | runday    | category_id | restaurant_id
1  |12            | 23      |2018-12-04 | 25          | 12
2  |12            | 45      |null       | null        | null
3  |15            | 23      |null       | null        | null
```

This is my excepted results table where `restaurant_id` and `Item_id` from `restaurant_items` and others from `new_sponsoreds`

In here first record match the `left outer join` because `restuarant_id` 12 is promoting there `category_id` 25 in 2018-12-04.

Second record doesn't matches even if it belongs to the same restaurant, it's `category_id` is not equals to the 25.

Third record has the same `category_id` as the first record. But it doesn't match the join because it belongs to a different restaurant.

This is my expected results. But I'm getting nothing after I added the left join part to my query. Why this could happen?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Move the last line up one

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT restaurant_items.*,new_sponsoreds.* FROM test2.restaurant_items
inner join items on restaurant_items.item_id = items.Item_id
inner join categories on items.category_id = categories.id
inner join restaurants on restaurant_items.restaurant_id = restaurants.Restaurant_id
left outer join new_sponsoreds on categories.id = new_sponsoreds.category_id
and new_sponsoreds.runday = current_date() and new_sponsoreds.restaurant_id = restaurants.Restaurant_id
where restaurants.region_id = 7 and categories.id = 33
```

As the comment suggested I move the lat line up one and added this part to the left outer join

```
and new_sponsoreds.restaurant_id = restaurants.Restaurant_id
```